# Рекурсивное построение массива на php

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица dep с полями id, dep (название), parent (id записи родителя).
Задача: отправить id в sql запрос, и в ответ принять многоуровневый ассоциативный массив по иерархии подчиненности в формате:

```
[
 {
    id: 1,
    parent: 'null',
    dep: 'Организация 1',
    children: [
        {
            id: 2,
            parent: '1',
            dep: 'Организация 2',
            children: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    parent: '2',
                    dep: 'Организация 3',
                    children : array('')
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

```
$response = array();            
$query = $dbh->prepare("select id, dep, parent from dep");
$query->execute();
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {$response[] = $row;}    //Заполняем массив response значениями из таблицы   

function createTree($arr){
    $parents_arr = array();
    foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
        $parents_arr[$item['parent']][$item['id']] = $item;
    }
        $treeElem = $parents_arr[null];  //Здесь мы объявляем абсолютными родителями элементы массива с parent=null
        generateElemTree($treeElem,$parents_arr);
    return $treeElem;
}   
    

function generateElemTree(&$treeElem, $parents_arr){
    foreach ($treeElem as $key=>$item){
        if(!isset($item['children'])){
            $treeElem[$key]['children'] = array();
        }
        if(array_key_exists($key, $parents_arr)){
            $treeElem[$key]['children']=$parents_arr[$key]; 
            generateElemTree($treeElem[$key]['children'], $parents_arr);
        }
    }
}
$cats=createTree($response);
echo json_encode($cats, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Сейчас я могу построить иерархию вложенности с помощью рекурсии только для записей, в которых parent=null. Как мне сделать то же самое, но для записей, в которых parent не равен нулю? Например, отправив в sql запрос id=2, получить массив, начинающийся с id=2 и включающий все подчиненнные записи? (Т.е. построить ветку начиная с заднного id). Заранее спасибо!

```
dep, CREATE TABLE `dep` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `dep` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

```
INSERT INTO `dep` (`id`,`dep`,`parent`) VALUES (1,'org1',NULL);
INSERT INTO `dep` (`id`,`dep`,`parent`) VALUES (2,'org1.1',1);
INSERT INTO `dep` (`id`,`dep`,`parent`) VALUES (3,'org1.1.1 ',2);
INSERT INTO `dep` (`id`,`dep`,`parent`) VALUES (4,'org1.1.1.1',3);
INSERT INTO `dep` (`id`,`dep`,`parent`) VALUES (5,'org1.1.1.1.1',4);
INSERT INTO `dep` (`id`,`dep`,`parent`) VALUES (6,'org1.1.1.1.1.1',5);
INSERT INTO `dep` (`id`,`dep`,`parent`) VALUES (7,'org1.1.1.1.1.2',5);


//Для id =1 
{
  "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "dep": "org1",
    "parent": null,
    "depth": "0",
    "children": {
      "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "dep": "org1.1",
        "parent": "1",
        "depth": "1",
        "children": {
          "3": {
            "id": "3",
            "dep": "org1.1.1 ",
            "parent": "2",
            "depth": "2",
            "children": {
              "4": {
                "id": "4",
                "dep": "org1.1.1.1",
                "parent": "3",
                "depth": "3",
                "children": {
                  "5": {
                    "id": "5",
                    "dep": "org1.1.1.1.1",
                    "parent": "4",
                    "depth": "4",
                    "children": {
                      "6": {
                        "id": "6",
                        "dep": "org1.1.1.1.1.1",
                        "parent": "5",
                        "depth": "5",
                        "children": []
                      },
                      "7": {
                        "id": "7",
                        "dep": "org1.1.1.1.1.2",
                        "parent": "5",
                        "depth": "5",
                        "children": []
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//Для id =4
{
  "4": {
    "id": "4",
    "dep": "org1.1.1.1",
    "parent": "3",
    "depth": "0",
    "children": {
      "5": {
        "id": "5",
        "dep": "org1.1.1.1",
        "parent": "4",
        "depth": "1",
        "children": {
          "6": {
            "id": "6",
            "dep": "org1.1.1.1",
            "parent": "5",
            "depth": "2",
            "children": []
          },
          "7": {
            "id": "7",
            "dep": "org1.1.1.1",
            "parent": "5",
            "depth": "2",
            "children": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая точную версию. Вы точно хотите всю эту ерунду крутить на PHP, или получение сразу требуемого JSON одним запросом тоже подойдёт?

Comment: *Сейчас я могу построить иерархию вложенности с помощью рекурсии только для записей, в которых parent=null. Как мне сделать то же самое, но для записей, в которых parent не равен нулю?* Построить от корня. Затем из результата убирать по уровню, пока на поверхности не окажется нужный узел. Ну или сразу "объявить нужный узел абсолютным родителем".

Comment: @Akina 1) MySQL 8.0 да конечно, я был бы очень благодарен за подсказку как сделать это без php! очень давно уже ломаю голову, но к сожалению навыки пока не позволяют придумать что-то лучше. 2) каким способом можно убирать по уровню, или же как можно объявить узел абсолютным родителем?

Comment: Выложите исходные данные таблицы (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, не более 10 записей), начальный ИД записи и требуемый финальный результат (JSON) для именно таких данных (можно 2-3 ИД, и для каждого - требуемый ответ). В данных предусмотрите все возможные варианты (главным образом - более 1 потомка).

Comment: @Akina добавил в первое сообщение. Уровень вложенности может быть до 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, 0 level
          FROM dep
          WHERE id = 1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT dep.*, cte1.level + 1
          FROM cte1
          JOIN dep ON cte1.id = dep.parent ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG( id, 
                                 JSON_OBJECT( 'id', id,
                                              'dep', dep,
                                              'depth', level,
                                              'parent', parent,
                                              'children', '[]' )) obj,
                 MAX(parent) parent,
                 level,
                 MAX(id) id
          FROM cte1
          GROUP BY level ),
cte3 AS ( ( SELECT id, level, obj, parent
            FROM cte2
            ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1 )
          UNION ALL
          SELECT cte2.id, 
                 cte2.level,
                 JSON_MERGE_PATCH(cte2.obj,
                                  JSON_OBJECT(cte2.id,
                                              JSON_OBJECT('children', cte3.obj))),
                 cte2.parent
          FROM cte3
          JOIN cte2 ON cte3.parent = cte2.id )
SELECT CAST(obj AS CHAR)
FROM cte3
WHERE level = 0;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c52b233b41bbac922809174b36c3eb14)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все работает

Comment: @ortah На всякий случай - возможно, что CAST в финальном запросе лишний, и достаточно простого `SELECT obj FROM cte3 WHERE level = 0;`. При этом будет передан тот же JSON, но как бинарная, а не текстовая, строка, что может быть (а может и не быть - надо смотреть) более подходяще для клиентской стороны.